# Is the "is being employed" bit in this sentence grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, progressive-aspect

> Mr. Peter **is being employed** at our company as "Marketing Supervisor" as of 01.01.2010 till date with a monthly salary of 0000.0000

Comment: It's semantically odd, at least. I wouldn't call it employment if his salary is zero—more like slavery.

Answer (score 3):

It's just about grammatical if it means that Mr Peter has only just been engaged. If he's already been working there for some time, you need to say 'Mr. Peter is employed at our company . . .'

Comment: Surely "... employed *by* our company."?

Comment: @TrevorD: Either is fine, although "employed by" is more common: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=employed+at%2C+employed+by&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence would read better if written as follows:

> 'Mr. Peter has been employed at our company as "Marketing Supervisor"
>   from 01.01.2010 to date, with a monthly salary of 000.'

(Note: The 'from.. to..' could be British English, and the 'as of.. till..' American English).

Answer (score 1):

Shebeer, your sentence is ungrammatical, as, in your understood intention to convey some timespan, you have wrongly mishmashed three temporal grammatical forms, one of which involves the preposition *as of*, another the construction *from ... to*, and the last one the preposition *since*.

*As of*(*) is never later in a sentence parallelled by *to/till*, because *as of* is used for situations whose truth is enduring, or more precisely, whose truth cannot later in the sentence be syntactically limited, e.g., by using function words such as *to*, *until*, *for* etc. (Semantically it can, of course: you can always add something like "it is falsely believed".) The structure *as of* + point in time (which point is allowed to be blurred) can be used in sentences such as these (quoted mostly from dictionaries):

> *- Darren terminated his job as of December 31st. The project was terminated as of January 1.
>
>   - As of last year, pupils are admitted according to where they live and go to school, and whether they already have siblings at the school.
>
>   - We begin work as of Tuesday.
>
>   - As of the moment, things are fine.
>
>   - As of next month, all the airline's fares will be going up.*
>   (! Note that in the latter sentence the progressive aspect has special use. It will not happen that starting with the following month, the situation will be such that the action will be progressive—that the price of the fares will have increased on a certain day (commonly, the first working day of the month), then, that it will have increased some more later in the day, then some more the next day, and so on. Rather, the sentence means that the fares are set to increase once more. This use is different from the one in the op.)

Please also read through these: *[as of today](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/blog.php?action=ViewBlogArticle&ba_id=341)* and *[as (of) yet](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/yet#as-of-yet)*.

You, also, wished to express the continuity of the situation stated, so you used a progressive aspect (in passive voice, but that's unimportant). You ought not to have additionally changed the default value of that grammatical category (a.k.a *simple* or *Simple*) for your verb; the preposition *as of*—in its interesting way—already denotes that the stated situation is not momentary. The preposition *since* is somewhat similar to *as of*, in that it denotes a more lasting situation. The similarity, to whatever extent, is only semantical, however. Syntactically, *since* conveys that the sitution is not momentary, by way of signalling and governing that perfect aspect (as required by standard English!) shall be used: *They **have** been friends **since** childhood. **She's** been skiing **since** childhood.* Dissimilarly to *since*, *as of* coexists quite fine with verbs having simple aspect.

So, you have mishmashed these three forms (I'll refrain from a more formal notation):

- is employed as of + past date
- was employed from + past date + to + endpoint less in past
- has been working since + past date

Additionally, you took *till date* ("*date*" meaning the time of the utterance) for your 'endpoint less in past', even though present perfect dispenses with the need for any temporal adverbial that means *now* such like "*till date*", which it does because a present perfect action implies that the endpoint less in the past is identical with the time of the utterance. Perhaps sensing this, you opted for present progressive, as it sort of resembles present perfect in that they never describe momentary situations. The result is a sentence of its own kind.

Therefore, a more grammatical sentence would be:

> Mr. Peter is employed at our company as "Marketing Supervisor" as of 01.01.2010 with a monthly salary of 0000.0000.

See? Only a couple of words deleted. But for a reason.

Still, the sentence is yet to be free of any grammatical errors, to my mind. I think the use of *at* with *employed* is incorrect in a sentence written from the perspective of the employee's employer. A detached observer will commonly use the collocation *employed at*, but the employer should use something less detached, such as *by* and *with* (again, in my opinion). Please read through [this](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/ask-teacher/149190-employed.html) (cf *He is employed, with a friend, at the local Burger King.*) and [this](http://talk.collegeconfidential.com/parents-forum/1388927-your-2012-college-grad-employed-3.html).

So, I propose the correct version is:

> Mr. Peter is employed by our company as "Marketing Supervisor" as of 01.01.2010 with a monthly salary of 0000.0000.

(*) That it is examined in [Business](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/as-of-date.html) Dictionary more carefully than in a number of other commonly used dictionaries, is illuminating as to whence this preposition came. In that light, the date of its first recorded use [(1900)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as+of?show=0&t=1379349097) also suggests it's a term of business/legal register that later seeped into less formal registers, to wich *as of today*, for example, belongs.